# How to exit method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a `UITextField` and I want to check if it is nil to stop executing the method and if it's not to continue. Here is my try, but it doesn't work:

```
if ([textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] == @"") {
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Does the code not work as expected, or doesn't it compile?

Comment: this is not the proper way to compare a string with an another one. try to use the `-isEqualToString:` method for the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you're checking to see if a text field is empty you don't need to remove spaces from it.

Comment: I'm not checking if empty. I'm checking if the text in the text field with spaces removed is equal to the empty string. This is intentional as my answer was based on the technique used by the OP.

Comment: I guess it's more of a comment of OP as his question said nil, which is wrong but implied an empty field but his example didn't.It's just an unnecessary step for an empty field.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if its nothing but whitespace, you should use

```
- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
```

and use the character set:

```
[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
```

Then see if the string has a length of 0 at the end

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
if([[textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] length] == 0) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: From the attempt, it looks like he want's to return if the user hasn't typed anything or has only typed whitespace (specifically spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so based on your question:

> "I have a UITextField and I want to check if it is nil"

then

```
if (!textField){
// Do whatever here
}
```

if you want to check if a text field is empty then

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    // Do whatever here
}
```

If the text field is empty then you shouldn't need to remove spaces from it.

if you need to check that x Number of chracters have been entered then I would use

```
if ([textField.text length] <= x){
// do whatever here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
if (![[textField text] length] > 0) {

    return;

}
```